Improve accuracy of ollama based llm model output
I have set up Ollama local usage for a chat with pdf.
When I ask questions or prompts, my responses are not getting the required output. Also, I have mixed combinations of pdf such as images and text in pdf. I need to extract only values present in the pdf. Kindly help in improving code accuracy and scalability.
import logging
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain.retrievers.multi_query import MultiQueryRetriever
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)

def load_pdf(file_path: str):
    """Load a PDF file and return the document data."""
    try:
        loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(file_path=file_path)
        data = loader.load()
        logging.info("PDF loaded successfully")
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to load PDF: {e}")
        raise

def split_text(data, chunk_size=7500, chunk_overlap=100):
    """Split the text into chunks using a text splitter."""
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(data)
    logging.info(f"Text split into {len(chunks)} chunks")
    return chunks

def create_vector_db(chunks, model_name="nomic-embed-text", index_name="faiss_index"):
    """Create a vector database from text chunks and save it locally."""
    try:
        embedding_model = OllamaEmbeddings(model=model_name)
        vectorstore_db = FAISS.from_documents(documents=chunks, embedding=embedding_model)
        vectorstore_db.save_local(index_name)
        logging.info(f"Vector database created and saved as {index_name}")
        return vectorstore_db.as_retriever()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error creating vector database: {e}")
        raise

def initialize_llm(model_name="llama3"):
    """Initialize the LLM model."""
    try:
        llm = ChatOllama(model=model_name)
        logging.info(f"LLM model {model_name} initialized")
        return llm
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error initializing LLM model: {e}")
        raise

def create_query_prompt():
    """Create a query prompt template."""
    return PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["question"],
        template="""You are a virtual assistant given the important task of taking a set of given and using that context and only 
                    that context to answer a query in an intelligent manner. Try your hardest to find the answer within the context. 
                    Do not under any circumstances use any outside knowledge not found in the documents. If the answer isn't within the documents, respond with 'Not found'.
                    Original question: {question}"""
    )

def create_chain(retriever, llm):
    """Create a processing chain for the document retrieval and response generation."""
    query_prompt = create_query_prompt()

    rag_template = """Answer the question based ONLY on the following context:
                      {context}
                      Question: {question}"""
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(rag_template)

    chain = (
        {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
        | prompt
        | llm
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    logging.info("Processing chain created")
    return chain

def main():
    local_path = "Loan_Package_Upload-001.pdf"

    # Load and process the PDF document
    data = load_pdf(local_path)
    chunks = split_text(data)

    # Create a vector database and retriever
    vector_retriever = create_vector_db(chunks)

    # Initialize the LLM
    llm = initialize_llm()

    # Create and run the processing chain
    chain = create_chain(vector_retriever, llm)
    response = chain.invoke("Extract 'First Payment Due Date', mentioned under Promissory Note document under section A.")
    
    logging.info(f"Response: {response}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred in the main execution: {e}")

Sample prompt:
Extract 'First Payment Due Date', mentioned under Promissory Note document under section A.
Output from llm:
2024-08-12 15:55:18,781 - INFO - pikepdf C++ to Python logger bridge initialized
2024-08-12 15:56:34,532 - INFO - PDF loaded successfully
2024-08-12 15:56:34,562 - INFO - Text split into 12 chunks
2024-08-12 15:57:05,019 - INFO - Loading faiss with AVX2 support.
2024-08-12 15:57:05,089 - INFO - Successfully loaded faiss with AVX2 support.
2024-08-12 15:57:05,099 - INFO - Vector database created and saved as faiss_index
2024-08-12 15:57:05,109 - INFO - LLM model llama3 initialized
2024-08-12 15:57:05,109 - INFO - Processing chain created
2024-08-12 15:57:30,925 - INFO - Response: I apologize, but there is no mention of "First Payment Due Date" in the provided context, which appears to be a Promissory Note document for a loan. The document does not explicitly state the "First Payment Due Date".


